# SVN Wordpress keeps asking for authentication when providing correct credentials

Tags: wordpress, authentication, svn

I'm having trouble commiting to my wordpress plugin after switching to a new laptop. I did a checkout to retrieve the repository again after which I made changes and tried committing them.

However, each time I try to commit it replies `Authentication realm: <https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org:443> Use your WordPress.org login` and asks for my credentials again and again (even with `--username myusername --password mypassword`), until it returns `No more credentials or we tried too many times.`.

I have tried clearing my svn password cache, am aware that the username is case sensitive and also tried installing subversion using brew, without any luck.

From my old laptop, it still works. But it is unclear to me what is different in my new setup.